# Laravel 5.1 - Admin panel - Update User

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

i have a problem editing user registered, i need update information user but i have problem:

- Update email user, (error email exist), i need ignore email that user editing.
- Other information doesnt update.
- Update password IF insrted new password.

i'm using resource controller.

UserController.php

```
namespace dixard\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use dixard\Http\Requests;
use dixard\Http\Controllers\Controller;

// colleghiamo al modello

use dixard\User;

// ci serve per validare
use Validator;

//per aggionare password
use Hash;    


public function update(Request $request, User $user)
        {

            $id= $user->id;
            // i want ignora id of user edited
            $rules = [

                'name' => 'required',

                'lastname' => 'required',

                'username' => 'required|max:50|',

                'birth' => 'required',

                'country' => 'required',

                'usertype' => 'required',

                'email' => 'required|email|unique:users'.',email,' . $id,


            ];

            $messages = [


                'name.required' => 'Campo nome richiesto',
                'lastname.required' => 'Campo cognome richiesto',
                'username.required' => 'Campo username richiesto',
                'username.max' => 'Campo massimo 50 caratteri',
                'birth.required' => 'Campo nascita richiesto',
                'country.required' => 'Campo paese richiesto',
                'usertype.required' => 'Campo tipologia richiesto',
                'email.required' => 'Campo email richiesto',
                'email.email' => 'formato email errato ',

                'email.unique' => 'Email già esistente',
                'password.min' => 'Campo password minimo 4 caratteri',
                'password.max' => 'Campo password massimo 18 caratteri',



            ];


            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
            if ($validator->fails()){

                return redirect('admin/user')->withErrors($validator);

            }
            // if there is not any error go to update
            else{           

                // if email id different by input, so if email input update also email
                if( $user->email != $request->email ){

                $s = new User;

                $data = array(

                     'name'             => $request->get('name'),
                'lastname'     => $request->get('lastname'),
                'username'          => $request->get('username'),
                'email'         => $request->get('email'),
                'password'      => $request->get('password'),
                'birth'         => $request->get('birth'),
                'country'       => $request->get('country'),
                'usertype'          => $request->get('usertype'),


                );

                $s->where($id, $request->get('id'))->update($data);

                return redirect('admin/user')->with('message', 'Updated successfully');
                }

                // If email input doesnt change update all ( not email)
                else{

                $s = new User;

                $data=array(

                    'name'          => $request->get('name'),
                'lastname'     => $request->get('lastname'),
                'username'          => $request->get('username'),

                'password'      => $request->get('password'),
                'birth'         => $request->get('birth'),
                'country'       => $request->get('country'),
                'usertype'          => $request->get('usertype'),


                     );

                $s->where($id, '=', $request->get('id'))->update($data);

                return redirect('admin/user')->with('message-error', 'error');


                }

            }
        }
```

ROUTES.PHP

```
Route::resource('admin/user','Admin\UserController');



Route::bind('user', function($user){

    return dixard\User::find($user);
});
```

model USER.PHP

```
    protected $table = 'users';


    protected $fillable = [

    'name',
    'username',
    'lastname',
    'birth',
    'profile',
    'country',
    'usertype',
    'email',
    'password',
    'social',
    'confirm_token',
    'active',

    ];

    // Ogni utente HA tanti prodotti.

    public function products() 
    {

        return $this->hasMany('dixard\Product');    

    }


    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    // setare la password ogni volta che viene cambiata

    public function setPasswordAttribute($valor){
        //se non è vuota viene applicato hash
       if(!empty($valor)) {

        $this->attributes['password']= \Hash::make($valor);   
       }


    }
```

EDIT.PHP view page

{!! Form::open(['route'=>'admin.user.update', 'class'=>'form-horizontal form-label-left']

```
                )!!}


                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Nome<span class="required">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <input type="text"  id="name"  name="name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="{{$user->name}}">
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="lastname">Cognome<span class="required">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <input type="text" id="lastname"  name="lastname" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="{{$user->lastname}}">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  .... So for all fields inputs


                      <a href="{{url('admin/user')}}" class="btn btn-warning">cancel</a>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">update</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                {!! Form::close()!!}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route, and add the user id to it, since it's an update method:

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=> ['admin.user.update', $user->id], ...])!!}
```

You didn't pass the user id to the route, so in your controller the User will be null probably. In this case, the validation won't pass, since the id is null, so won't skip the current user, and it checks against all records in the users table.

Comment: I added on form: {!! Form::open(['route'=> ['admin.user.update', $user->id], ...])!!}     Now i have this ERROR ---->                                                    SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '45' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `users` set `name` = test, `lastname` = test, `username` = test, `email` = test@test.com, `password` = 123456, `birth` = 2008-07-24, `country` = Italy, `usertype` = 0, `updated_at` = 2016-05-06 17:24:54 where `45` is null)

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
'email' => 'required|email|unique:users'.',email,' . $id,
```

To :

```
'email'  =>  'required|email]unique:users,email,'.$id,
```